# Is it possible to have the same WordPress theme and content in a Multi-site?

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I wish to setup a site that when visitors are from Australia or New Zealand, they are redirected from the .com (main site) to .com.au or .co.nz. Is this possible to setup with a WordPress Multi-site using the same theme and that when the content is updated on the main site (.com) the rest of the sites (.com.au or .co.nz) are also updated? I do know how to redirect visitors based from their IP.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect an user to a specific domain depending of his country through htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on

#Australia
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^AU$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yourwebsite.com.au/$1 [L]

#New Zealand
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^NZ$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yourwebsite.co.nz/$1 [L]
```

If you dont have GeoIP on your server check [that link](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/mod_geoip2/).
Be sure that your dns for .com.au and .co.nz are correctly set on your server then in your wp-config add the following lines :

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

You may want to check too on the [MultiDomain](https://wordpress.org/plugins/multidomain/) plugin for Wordpress.